# What are objective values can smart contract be aware of while executing?

Tags: contract-development

I had found that smart contract can't be aware of and check nonce of msg.sender.
It would be appreciated if you let me know which of many basis values for verification that smart contract is able to be aware of and utilize while executing. The values that can replace the nonce of msg.sender.

Thank you!

Comment: what kind of verification are you looking for?

Comment: I'd like to design contract as following.
1.I am gonna give data with my signed data to user who have permission from me to sign it to execute my contract.
2. Once the user sign it, the tx will be broadcasted.

However in this case, if user request cancellation the permission after he receive the data of transaction, then it is possible he can broadcast tx without me and execute my contract becuase has my signature already.

How can I prevent this? I had thought nonce is key but contract can't see nonce right?

Comment: @LauriPeltonen could you please see my comment?

Comment: Honestly, I did read it but I couldn't understand it so I gave up. The comments section is not meant for extended discussion anyway, so if you have clarifications for your original question just edit the question